# React Typescript SSR with monorepo project structure

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, express, server-side-rendering

My project is currently structured like this:

```
my-project/
    client/
        src/
        dist/
            index.html
        package.json
        tsconfig.json
    server/
        src/
        dist/
        package.json
        tsconfig.json
    common/
        src/
        dist/
        package.json
        tsconfig.json
    package.json
```

`client` is a React application; `server` both serves the client's `dist` files and functions as an API for it; and `common` is a package with things used by both `client` and `server`.

**Each subfolder has its own `tsconfig` configuration and `dist` folder.**

It worked great until I needed to implement SSR.

I started with adding `app.get('*', loadAppContent);` to the Express instance.

```js
import React from 'react';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import {StaticRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Request, Response} from 'express';

import App from '../../client/src/App';


export function loadAppContent(req: Request, res: Response) {
    fs.readFile(path.resolve('../client/dist/index.html'), 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return res.status(500).send('An error occurred');
        }

        const markup = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
            <StaticRouter context={{}} location={req.url}>
                <App/>
            </StaticRouter>
        );

        return res.send(
            data.replace(
                '<div id="app"></div>',
                `<div id="app">${markup}</div>`
            )
        );
    });
}
```

Now, when I try to compile `server`, it tries to also compile `client` (since there's an import to `App`, which is inside `client`). It also means that the `dist` folder of `server` turns from:

```
dist/
    index.ts
    server.files.ts
```

To:

```
dist/
    client/
        src/App.tsx
        client.files.ts
    server/
        index.ts
        server.files.ts
```

`client` gets compiled with the wrong settings (since it has its own `tsconfig` file!).

## Possible approaches

Here are some possible solutions I could think of but couldn't make them work:

- **Compile all three packages to the same `dist` folder:** Might be possible, but it means that `client` will have to override the wrong compilation of `server`, and the custom `tsconfig` issue isn't solved.
- **Prevent `server` from compiling the `client` code it imports:** Sounds like the best solution, but I couldn't configure `./server/tsconfig.json` in such a way.

If you have any idea (or need any kind of additional information), let me know. <3

Answer (score -1):

I am sorry in advance for my short answer, but could I suggest you to divide your single repo into two separate repos ? One that would only run the back and one that would serve the front, then host them on separate servers.

My previous structure was like yours and it became very painfull over time. Creating two repos and hosting them on different server is way better in every way.

Considering your first approach it can work:

- You can configure each .tsconfig to exclude files of other folders.
- You should have a dist/ folder in your my-project folder
- Instead of compiling each folder 'by hand' then copy-past it into the main /dist/ repo you can use gulp, it will help you create your dist/ in one line command (basically you will have to tell him to compile the server, then put it in dist, then compile the front, then put it in dist/client

Considering your second approach, you should compile the server before putting the client code inside (then create another /dist folder)

Is creating two repos totally off the table ?